# InputStream to int array

Tags: java, arrays, url, inputstream

Good evening!

I have been reading through stuff on the internet for hours now but I can't find any way to get the conent of a file from the internet into an int array.

I got a .txt file (that I download from the internet) which is loaded over a BufferedStreamInput. There is a byte array which I tried to make use of it, but didn't have much success. Inside the file are random letters such as "abcCC". Now I would need the int value of each character (such as 97,98,99,67,67). I would add them to an array and then count how often a specific value appears. My problem tho is to get those values from the stream and I don't seem to find a way to do so.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you add some example of input, expected output, and explanation why such output would be expected?

Comment: In what base the ints in the file are? How are they encoded?

Comment: It's a .txt with random letters like "gdjghJHKGKjhgjkg" in there. I need those characters as ints (and cast them to char later) and count how often a specific (int) value appears.

Let's say the input/the file would be "abcCC", then I would need int values such as 97,98,99,67,67 (or whatever the exact values art). The rest is no problem.. I just can't find a way to get those values.

Comment: @user3602302: Please update the question accordingly - this makes it much easier for everyone to understand the problem...

Comment: To update your question use [[edit]] option placed under your post. Also have you tried reading content of your file line-by-line? This way you would get String which would represent each line, which you could change into `char[]` array using `toCharArray()` method. Then (if I am guessing correctly) you can just cast each of characters from string to int like `int intValue = (int)characters[i]` where `i` is index of character from your Stirng.

Comment: I updated my question and hope it is a bit more clear now :)

I tried to do it via readline before but then noticed I have to get it to int before I cast it to char =/

Comment: "*but then noticed I have to get it to int before I cast it to char*" `char` can be treated as `int` in many ways... This looks like [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe why you need `int`s representation of `char`?

Comment: @Pshemo I do believe he indicated in his original post that it is a requirement of his assignment to read the characters as `int` directly from the file. (Hence my answer which references the no-arg `read()` method.

Comment: @Brendan `read` could be be solution, but also source of many problems. We don't know about encoding OP is using in his input file (what if it is UTF-16 where characters are written on two bites?). Also what about range of characters? Are there only the ones from 0-255 range of Unicode table? I don't see this question as well described or useful for someone else beside OP that is why it is hard for me to upvote any answer :/

Comment: @Pshemo You're right, I added those assumptions to my answer. But I would find it strange for an assignment which reads `int` from a string of characters and casts to `char` to include working with the mess that is character encoding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java API already contains a method that seems very convenient for you. [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) defines the following method.

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException;
```

> *Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.*

It should make it trivial to read integers from a file one byte at a time (assuming characters to integers is one-to-one; `int` is actually four bytes in size).

---

An example of using this method to read characters individually as `int` and then casting to `char` follows. Again, this assumes that each character is encoded as a single byte, and that there is a one-to-one from characters to `int`s. If you're dealing with multi-byte character encoding and/or you want to support integers greater than 255, then the problem becomes more complex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("abc".getBytes());
    int value;
    while ((value = in.read()) > -1) {
        System.out.println((char) value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a

```
java.util.Scanner.
```

You can initialize it with many different options including

```
File 
InputStream
Readable
```

Later you can process the whole input line by line or in any way you like.
please refer to the great javadoc of Scanner.

Regards,

z1pi